# Real methods for the evaluating $\int^{\pi/2}_{0}\cos(nt)\cos^m(t)\,dt$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, beta-function

One can show by integrating the following function

$$f(z) = z^{n-m-1}(1+z^2)^m$$

around the following contour

[image]

By equating the circular part of $|z|=1$ and the line on the imaginary part.

$$\int^{\pi/2}_{0}\cos(nt)\cos^m(t)\,dt=2^{-m}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi -m\pi}{2} \right)\int^1_{0}t^{n-m-1}(1-t^2)^m\,dt \tag{1}$$

The left side looks close to the Beta representation

$$2\int^{\pi/2}_0 \sin^{2n-1}(t) \cos^{2m-1}(t)\,dt = \frac{\Gamma(n)\Gamma(m)}{\Gamma(n+m)} \tag{2}$$

**Questions**

- Can we show (1) using elementary transformations ?
- What real methods can we use to prove the integral

$$\int^{\pi/2}_{0}\cos(nt)\cos^m(t)\,dt=\frac{\pi \Gamma(m+1)}{2^{m+1}\Gamma\left(\frac{n+m+2}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{2-n+m}{2}\right)}\tag{3}$$

Comment: If someone is interested in the full contour solution http://advancedintegrals.com/2017/04/integrating-a-function-around-three-branches-using-a-semi-circle-contour/

Comment: It seems that $$\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^n(t)\cos^m(t)\, \mathrm dt = \frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{m+1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}{2 \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2(m+n+2)}\right)}$$ will play a special part in this. I have had it show up in my intermediary calculations, but I am evidently missing something

Comment: $$\int^{\pi/2}_{0}\cos(nt)\cos^m(t)\,dt = \int^{\pi/2}_{0}\cos^m(t)\sum_{k=0}^n \left[{n \choose k}\cos^k(t)\sin^{n-k}(t)\cos\left(\frac{\pi n-\pi k}{2}\right)\right]\,dt$$

Comment: When I assume the integral can be brought inside. I haven't checked; it's far too late at night and no progress seems to be made.
$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}\cos\left(\frac{\pi n-\pi k}{2}\right)\left[\int^{\pi/2}_{0}\cos^{m+k}(t)\sin^{n-k}(t)\,\mathrm d t\right]$$

$$\frac{1}{2 \Gamma \left(\frac{m+n+2}{2}\right)}\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}\cos\left(\frac{\pi n-\pi k}{2}\right)\Gamma \left(\frac{m+1+k}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1-k}{2}\right)$$

Comment: My only other thought in this direction would be to try bringing the $\cos^m(t)$ inside of the summation and possibly taking out the sine from the sum... whatever it would take to solve the summation first

Comment: If I follow my above recommendation I get, from Mathematica,
$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}\cos^{m+k}(t)\sin^{-k}(t)\cos\left(\frac{\pi n-\pi k}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\cos^m(t)\left[\left(e^{it}\sin t\right)^{-n}+e^{i \pi n/2} (1-i \cot t)^n\right]$$
Which looks like it would yield a somewhat tractable approach if I actually did my calculations correctly, though bringing complex numbers in may or may not break the idea of "Real Analysis". Perhaps if the idea works I could find a way to rework the proof to avoid steps involving complex numbers.

Comment: Oh, and I'm writing this all in the middle of the night, so I might be making some blatant mistakes... if so, please let me know.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen, I suggest you convert your comments to an answer. Any idea is welcomed.