# Integrals that can't be solved by real methods

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

It seems that there are real integrals that are immune to all real methods of integration and one has to apply the residue theorem and contour integration. Here is my collection

$$\int_0^1 x^{-x}(1-x)^{x-1}\sin \pi x\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi}{e}\tag {1}$$

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(e^{x}-x)^{2}+{\pi}^{2}}=\frac{1}{1+W(1)}=\frac{1}{1+\Omega}\tag {2}$$

$$\int^{\pi/2}_{0}\cos(xt)\cos^y(t)\,\mathrm{d}t=\frac{\pi \Gamma(x+1)}{2^{y+1}\Gamma\left(\frac{x+y+2}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{2-x+y}{2}\right)}\tag{3}$$

$$\int_0^{1}\arctan\left(\frac{\mathrm{arctanh}\ x-\arctan{x}}{\pi+\mathrm{arctanh}\ x-\arctan{x}}\right)\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}=\frac{\pi}{8}\log\frac{\pi^2}{8} \tag {4}$$

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(e^x+x+1)^2+\pi^2}=\frac{2}{3}\tag {5}$$

Are there any other examples ?

**References**

1. https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h501365p2817263
2. [Interesting integral related to the Omega Constant/Lambert W Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45745/interesting-integral-related-to-the-omega-constant-lambert-w-function?noredirect=1&lq=1)
3. http://advancedintegrals.com/2017/04/integrating-a-function-around-three-branches-using-a-semi-circle-contour/
4. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.3830.pdf
5. [Integral: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{(e^x+x+1)^2+\pi^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1055468/integral-int-infty-infty-fracdxexx12-pi2/1055598#1055598)

Comment: but these integrals are not immune to numerical approximations, right (as Simpson rule or Euler-Maclaurin sum formula)? I mean, if an integral doesnt have a primitive expressible in elementary functions we need numerical integration methods, except for some special cases.

Comment: @Masacroso, of course but you won't get that nice closed form solution like the first one using approximations. My question isn't about integrals that can't be expresses using elementary function's rather those where contour integrations seem superior.

Comment: In the third integral, if m,n>0 are integers, no need contour integration imho

Comment: @FDP, They are real. Hence the use of the Gamma function.

Comment: I changed $m,n $ to $x,y $ so they are not confused to be integers.

Comment: For your last one, $$-\frac{\cos x}{2(2\cos x+e^{\sqrt{3}x})}$$ is a primitive function, so that one is trivial. Also, your question would be better if you gave the source and some argument for your examples.

Comment: @mickep, you are right. I will add the references , the complex functions and contours later.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1055468/integral-int-infty-infty-fracdxexx12-pi2/1055598#1055598

Comment: Real and imaginary parts of Fourier transforms most of the time require residue theorem. To my knowledge, $\int_\Bbb R \frac{\cos x}{1+x^2}dx$ can't be found by "real methods".

Comment: @RonGordon, thanks added.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy, I always thought the same. Not sure if that's true.

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai i'm quite confident that $(3)$ can be done without contour integrals/residue theorem. Furthermore https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253910/the-integral-that-stumped-feynman might ne intersting for you

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai How does one know a definite integral, which can be evaluated using complex analysis, cannot be evaluated using real analysis only?

Comment: @TZakrevskiy [See This Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2236261/find-the-fourier-cosine-transform-of-the-function-defined-by-displaystyle-fx/2236287#2236287) in which I presented a real analysis method for evaluating the Fourier Cosine Transform $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(\omega x)}{1+x^2}\,dx$.

Comment: @tired Of course, Feynman's failure doesn't imply that it is impossible.  In fact, since the residue theorem is effectively a consequence of Green's Theorem in the plane, contour integration can be translated into an equivalent problem of analysis in the real plane.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @tired, I feel the same towards  (3) but never seen a solution that involves only real methods. Actually I posted that question around two weeks ago nobody responded https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2227196/real-methods-for-the-evaluating-int-pi-2-0-cosnt-cosmt-dt

Comment: @Dr.MV, I don't know. But the easiness of solving the integral using contour integration seems to deviate people from trying real analysis methods. Something like (1) seems to take contour integration to another level with the complex parametrization it involves .

Comment: Zaid, I'd love to see references or links to where these integrals have been evaluated.  Do you have them? -Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV, I will add everything later. I am quite ill and only using my phone.

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai I hope you feel better soon.

Comment: Probably a piece of cake for Ramanujan to derive these results, but note that he didn't know about complex analysis until quite late in his short life.

Comment: @Dr.MV some quick thinking makes your argument plausible, but i have never seen an actual prove for this equivalence. Can you provide one? the problem seems to to translate the concept of holomorpic functions appropriately

Comment: @tired It's fairly straightforward, but a bit too long for a comment.  I'd post a solution if someone posted the question.  -Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV I included the references for proofs of all the questions. Most of the links are external unfortunately.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1819837/integral-int-infty-infty-frac-gammax-sin-pi-x-gamma-leftxa-rig?rq=1

This has no real solution....

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331148/interesting-integral-int-infty-infty-fracei-nx-gamma-alphax-g?rq=1

Comment: @Dr.MV that's quite nice, thank you.

Comment: Do you mean log (base 10) or ln ?